# Branch.io deep links stopped to work after config Firebase app on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, branch.io, deeplink

I had Branch.io deep links on iOS working correctly for months but when I implemented a sign in on Firebase app in order to get an `id token` I noticed that branch deep links stopped to work. If I remove the Firebase sign in deep links works perfectly but I need to have Firebase sign in implemented. I expended almost three days trying to find a solution I need help.
Did you experience a similar issue?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the deep link issue setting the Firebase app configuration before the branch init session. It is weird because I couldn't realize what is happening when I set branch first. I also asked for help to branch.io support but they told me that they never experienced problems with Firebase integration.
I could realize how to fix the issue reading the doc on branch site: https://docs.branch.io/integrations/google-firebase/

1. Ensure you've completed the Firebase SDK implementation as
   documented here
2. Ensure you've completed the Branch SDK implementation as documented here.
3. In the AppDelegate of the Branch iOS SDK, update the implementation as below:

`FirebaseApp.configure()
Branch.getInstance().initSession(...`